# Is it possible to always right-align the AG-grid column menu?

Tags: alignment, ag-grid, contextmenu

I have an ag-grid with a mix of left and right aligned columns. The column menu shows up on the right side for left-aligned and on the left side for right-aligned columns.
Is there a way to force it to always show on the right side, regardless of column's text alignment? I could not find anything in the documentation.

Tried changing column alignment, fiddling with column menu options, could not find any option to fix the column menu alignment.

Answer (score 0):

Menu icon will position itself based on the header alignment, not the column. You can have the header left-aligned (default) and the rows cells aligned right by using a cell class like this:

`cellClass: 'text-right'`

If you wish to have both the cells and the header on the right, you need to use a custom css for the header. The css style below will also maintain the menu icon on the right, instead of the default left position :

In the grid columns' definition:

```
headerClass: 'ag-header-right`
cellClass: 'text-right'
```

and in css:

```
.ag-header-right {
  ag-header-cell-label {
  justify-content: right;
  margin-right: 10px;
  }
}
```